# Easily access the favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

Many users open StackOverFlow and check the tags which they like the most. Since we have Favorite tags(which contains users favorite tags), it should be rather placed **above** 'Unanswered tags'. This way, users will be able to access the favorite tags easily. He need not grope through the big list of tags and go to his favorite area of expertise or interest.

Comment: Uh, my favorite tags *are* displayed above "unanswered tags", whatever those are. Are you looking in the column to the right on the homepage?

Comment: When Unanswered button is clicked. At that instance when user wants to check the unanswered queries of his interests, the fav tags wont be on top right corner. I was just suggesting it would be nice if it was on the top. Nothing else.

Comment: On my version of Stack Overflow, the unanswered tags displayed at the top *are* my favorite tags. Does your screen look different?

Comment: Go to main StackOverFlow, click Unanswered button, now check the top right side. You will not find favorite tags on the top. If it is present there, users can directly check the unanswered questions from his fav tags(whichever he clicks on). As of now, he has to scroll down and select the tag. Am talking only about this context(Go to main StackOverFlow, click Unanswered button, now check the top right side.).

Comment: Got that. But the *exact same tags* are displayed in both sets. Not sure what the problem is. I don't have to do any scrolling.

Comment: oh ok. Well for me its not like that. Its different on landing @ http://stackoverflow.com/ and @ http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Comment: Thats the reason why I had raised this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that most questions (I would guess around 85%) on the [Stackoverflow homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/) are questions with your favorite tags? So you don't have to "grope through the big list of tags and go to [your] favorite area of expertise or interest", your favorite questions are right on the front page!

Comment: True. Well I have to scroll till the end of the page at times to get to my fav tag. So why not place them on top of 'Unaswered tags'